# SQL Server Find the date in joining order

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, intervals

I am using MS-SQL Server there are two tables

membership

```
+---+-----------------+---------------------+----------------
|   | membershipName  |      createddate    |   price       |
+---+-----------------+---------------------+----------------
| 1 | Swimming        |        2010-01-01   |     30        |
| 2 | Swimming        |        2010-05-01   |     32        |
| 3 | Swimming        |        2011-01-01   |     35        |
| 4 | Swimming        |        2012-01-01   |     40        |
+---+-----------------+---------------------+----------------
```

member

```
+---+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------
|   | memberName      |      membership     |   joiningDate  |
+---+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------
| 0 | Andy            |        Swimming     |    2008-02-02  |   
| 1 | John            |        Swimming     |    2010-02-02  |
| 2 | Andy            |        Swimming     |    2011-02-02  |
| 3 | Alice           |        Swimming     |    2015-02-02  |
+---+-----------------+---------------------+----------------
```

I want find the member's membership price for the right period of time

e.g

- Andy  return NULL
- John  return 30
- Alice return 40

the best logic is to see

if the joiningDate is in between two start date

```
 if yes choose the earlier date
```

if not

```
   if the joining date is before the earlier date then use the earliest date
   if the joining date is after  the latest  date then use the latest date
```

I am a Java programmer, do this in sql is quite tricky for me, any hint would be nice!

- edit 1: sorry I forgot to consider month
- edit 2: added desirable result

Comment: Why not just extract the year from `joiningDate` and join on it? `on membership.createdDate = year(member.joiningDate) and Membership.membershipName=Member.MembershipName`  It appears prices are yearly....  The year function will extract a year from a date datatype.  So only John(1) an Andy(2) would get prices while  Andy (0) and Alice(3) would not.  As you have no prices for those years.  if an INNER JOIN you would lose records 0 and 3 if a left join from member to membership you would KEEP the members but have no prices for them.

Comment: @xQbert I think, that exactly this *you would KEEP the members but have no prices for them* is the point... The OP wants to choose the first / last price for them.

Comment: @xQbert I am so sorry, I forgot the month in my example... in my real app, any given day a new membership definition can be created

Comment: so do you want prices for mebmer 0 and 3?  Since there's no price for 2008?  I can see setting Alice 3 to $40 because you don't have a date after 2012 so it would default to $40 as the "current price" but that logic fails for 2008 member.

Comment: @xQbert yes year 2008 would return null, because the membership wasn't created.. but Alice has to be $40 because swimming -4 is the latest price and thanks for your help sir

Comment: this is a terrible design.  why not just include the fk to membership in the members table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I got this correctly. You might try it like this:

Declared table variable to *mock-up* a test scenario:

```
DECLARE @membership TABLE(id INT, membershipName VARCHAR(100),createddate DATETIME,price DECIMAL(10,4));
INSERT INTO @membership VALUES
 (1,'Swimming',{d'2010-01-01'},30)
,(2,'Swimming',{d'2010-05-01'},32)
,(3,'Swimming',{d'2011-01-01'},35)
,(4,'Swimming',{d'2012-01-01'},40);

DECLARE @member TABLE(id INT,memberName VARCHAR(100),membership VARCHAR(100),joiningDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @member VALUES
 (0,'Andy','Swimming',{d'2008-02-02'})   
,(1,'John','Swimming',{d'2010-02-02'})
,(2,'Andy','Swimming',{d'2011-02-02'})
,(3,'Alice','Swimming',{d'2015-02-02'});
```

As you are on SQL-Server 2012 you are lucky. You can use `LEAD`:

The CTE "Intervalls" will return the membership table *as is* and it will add one column with one second before the next rows `createddate`. `LEAD` helps you to get hands on a value of a *later coming* row. First I take away one second, then I set a very high date in case of `NULL`:

```
WITH Intervalls AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ISNULL(DATEADD(SECOND ,-1,LEAD(createddate) OVER(ORDER BY createddate)),{d'2100-01-01'}) AS EndOfIntervall
    FROM @membership AS ms
)
```

--The `SELECT` reads all members and joins them to the membership where their date is in the range according to "Intervalls". Only the case *ealier than the first* must be treated specially:

```
SELECT m.*
      ,ISNULL(i.price, CASE WHEN YEAR(m.joiningDate)<(SELECT MIN(x.createddate) FROM @membership as x) 
                            THEN (SELECT TOP 1 x.price FROM @membership AS x ORDER BY x.createddate ASC) END)
FROM @member AS m
LEFT JOIN Intervalls AS i ON m.joiningDate BETWEEN i.createddate AND i.EndOfIntervall
```

### UPDATE Better approach (thx to Paparis)

```
SELECT m.*
      ,ISNULL(Corresponding.price, (SELECT TOP 1 x.price FROM @membership AS x ORDER BY x.createddate ASC)) AS price
FROM @member AS m
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 ms.price 
    FROM @membership AS ms
    WHERE ms.createddate<=m.joiningDate
    ORDER BY ms.createddate DESC
) AS Corresponding
```

### UPDATE 2: Even simpler!

```
SELECT m.*
      ,ISNULL
      (
          (
            SELECT TOP 1 ms.price 
            FROM @membership AS ms
            WHERE ms.createddate<=m.joiningDate
            ORDER BY ms.createddate DESC
          ), 
          (
            SELECT TOP 1 x.price FROM @membership AS x ORDER BY x.createddate ASC
          )
      ) AS price
FROM @member AS m
```

Comment: sorry I updated the membership table by adding month to it. thanks for your answer, let me take a look

Comment: @JunchenLiu Your edit breaks this completely... Which version of SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: I am so sorry. sql server 2012

Comment: @JunchenLiu If there are differen memberships you'll have to add the membershipname to the join condition with `AND`...

Comment: yes I know, that should be simple enough, but I am still struggling to understand the Intervalls, why would you want to add a second to the createddate?

Comment: @JunchenLiu I **subtract** it. `BETWEEN` is inclusive on both ends. If a membership starts exactly at the date of a new price, it would be counted to both intervalls. That's why I go back one second to set a decent border.

Comment: @JunchenLiu It might be cleaner to let the `DATEADD` away and use `date >= start AND date<end` instead of the `BETWEEN`...

Comment: @JunchenLiu, That is what I just wrote: *greater or equal* on the low border and *less-than* on the upper border...

Comment: thank you very much. helpfully this will help others as well

Comment: @JunchenLiu Hi, Papris answer brought me to a completely different and much better approach. See my update

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understood you correctly. try this out:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ms.Price
FROM membership ms
LEFT JOIN member m
ON m.joiningdate > ms.createdate
WHERE m.id = 3
ORDER BY price DESC
```

Comment: Great, so simple! My solution was much to complicated. According to your suggestion, which works for one row only, I updated mine and added a solution using this with `OUTER APPLY`. +1 from my side!